# advice how to make this code drier than it is now

Tags: javascript, loops

I am trying to reach this without usign so many main .textcontents

```
  main[0].textContent = randomNumber();
  main[1].textContent = randomNumber();
  main[2].textContent = randomNumber();
  main[3].textContent = randomNumber();
  main[4].textContent = randomNumber();
```

Tried to loop through it but something does not work
here is my code

```
<HTML>
 <div id="number-main" class="number-main">
          <div class="main" id="main1">0</div>
          <div class="main" id="main2">0</div>
          <div class="main" id="main3">0</div>
          <div class="main" id="main4">0</div>
          <div class="main" id="main5">0</div>
  </div>
</html>
```

```
const main = document.getElementsByClassName("main");
let points = [main[0], main[1], main[2], main[3], main[4]];


function randomNumber() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 50);
}


function myFunction() {
   for (let i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    return (points[i].textContent = randomNumber());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.main').forEach(
  div => div.textContent = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50)
)
```

```html
 <div id="number-main" class="number-main">
          <div class="main" id="main1">0</div>
          <div class="main" id="main2">0</div>
          <div class="main" id="main3">0</div>
          <div class="main" id="main4">0</div>
          <div class="main" id="main5">0</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: but why id do not let me use 


```
document.querySelectorAll('.main').forEach(
  div => div.textContent = randomNumber(); 
)
```

So without this code what u gave me randomNumber function works properly but after adding the code u gave me it gives me      error  >>> ("random number is not defined ")

Comment: You can still use the random number function if you like, just put it in before like ```function randomNumber() { ... } document.quierySelectorAll(...```

Answer (score 1):

First off, this line

```
let points = [main[0], main[1], main[2], main[3], main[4]];
```

is a bit strange, because you don't need to do it. While `getElementsByClassName` doesn't return an array, it does return a `HTMLCollection` which can be looped over with a `for` loop just as you did, so just can do:

```
const points = document.getElementsByClassName("main");
```

However if you ever do need to convert it to an array, there are better ways, than enumerating all the items manually, for example, with the spread operator:

```
const main = document.getElementsByClassName("main");
const points = [...main];
```

Or the `Array.from` method:

```
const main = document.getElementsByClassName("main");
const points = Array.from(main);
```

---

Your actually error here, is that you are using the `return` statement inside the `for` loop. `return` exits a function immediately, in your case while in the first iteration of the loop which aborts running the loop. Since your function doesn't need to actually return anything, you don't need to use it:

```
function myFunction() {
   for (let i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    points[i].textContent = randomNumber();
  }
}
```